# exporting org-mode subtree to a tree of text files

Tags: org-export

Is it possible to export an org-mode subtree to a directory tree of plaintext files, so that after exporting a subtree which looks (in principle) something like this:

```
** directory A
*** textfile b
    lorem ipsum
** directory C
*** directory D
**** textfile e
     dolor sit amet,
     consectetur adipiscing elit
**** textfile f
     sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
     ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
**** directory G
***** textfile h
      Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud
```

there appear the corresponding files like this:

```
$ find .
./A
./A/b
./C
./C/D
./C/D/e
./C/D/f
./C/D/G
./C/D/G/h
$ cat C/D/f
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
$  # etc.
```

Comment: **Q**: Is this built-in to `org-mode`?  **A**: No.  **Q**: Is it possible to write something up that can accomplish this?  **A**: Sure, this is Emacs we are talking about.  **Q**: How much time would be needed to write that up? **A**: Unknown.  **Q**: What level of Lisp skills would be required to write that up? **A**: Intermediate.